Clickhouse find max sum value per day
I have a clickhouse table where I store these (among many other) values.
plan_id, timestamp, client_id, account_id, product_id, total
One client_id can have many account_id, and each account_id can have many product_id. plan_id and product_id is 1:1, so one account_id can never have the same product_id twice.
Clients can move products from one plan in one account, to another plan in a different account.
I am trying to come up with a query that will return me all rows for a specific time when a product_id has the maximum value across all plans per client, based on the current timestamp plus the closest timestamp value for other entries of the same product. For example:



plan_id
timestamp
client_id
account_id
product_id
total




9d03
2024-02-02T05:23:00
7a954d98
4128
8905
480


9d03
2024-02-02T11:17:00
7a954d98
4128
8905
100


ff1d
2024-02-02T16:38:00
7a954d98
3127
8905
800


9d03
2024-02-02T02:55:17
7a954d98
4973
1150
900


9d03
2024-02-02T03:00:35
7a954d98
4973
1150
150


4baf
2024-02-02T13:50:15
7a954d98
2603
1150
150


b64e
2024-02-01T12:00:00
7a954d98
7040
4076
900


b64e
2024-02-02T03:00:35
7a954d98
7040
4076
150



For the above table, and product_id 8905 it should return this as even thought plan_id 9d03 was higher at 05:23:00, later in the day there is a sum value that is higher



plan_id
timestamp
client_id
account_id
product_id
total




9d03
2024-02-01T11:17:00
7a954d98
4128
8905
100


ff1d
2024-02-01T16:38:00
7a954d98
3127
8905
800



For the above table, and product_id 1150 it should return this as is when the value was higher.



plan_id
timestamp
client_id
account_id
product_id
total




9d03
2024-02-01T02:55:17
7a954d98
4973
1150
900



For the above table, and product_id 4076 it should return this as even though there is a row for 2024-02-01, at the beginning of 2024-02-02, the value was 900, which is higher than the one at 2024-02-02T03:00:35



plan_id
timestamp
client_id
account_id
product_id
total




b64e
2024-02-01T12:00:00
7a954d98
7040
4076
900



I have tried everything I can think of but currently the only way I found to this this is programmatically with a task, every minute (since there can be thousands of records) I query clickhouse and get all rows from the database before my timestamp, ordered by descending timestamp and limiting to 1 by plan_id. Since I have thousands of records, performance is taking a hit, so I wondered if there would be a query I could do after the day has passed.
I tried many queries but couldn't make it work, so I ended up doing it programmatically.

hi And - I spent a little time working on your problem, but I'm not fully understanding the logic. Perhaps if you could put into sample SQL or even pseudo-SQL what you're trying to achieve, that might help. Or show some examples of the queries you've tried, since that might show what you're trying to do.

It sounds like you may be able to use the ClickHouse function argMax() to return row based on the maximum value of one column [https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/reference/argmax]
Another solution might include using the AggregatingMergeTree table engine


I might have worded it poorly, but I think the examples I posted give a general idea. I don't need the maximum total by product it, I need to return all the rows where the aggregated total is the highest.

hi And - if I were to describe the aggregation then, would it be "give me the max total sum for product_id = X for the aggregation of any 2 consecutive rows by timestamp" ? this sounds like a WINDOW function of any 2 consecutive rows by timestamp by product_id

Not necessarily two rows. It could be two or it could be hundreds. But yes, the idea is to return all rows where between all product_id of the same type, limiting it to 1 by plan_id and all being the closest to the timestamp. I hope that makes sense :)

maybe LIMIT BY ... could help?
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/limit-by

Okay - sorry one more question (I work for ClickHouse and will ask around the team here for ideas) - how do you define how many rows are included in the aggregation? What exactly does "closest to the timestamp mean"? I think you will need to define a specific WINDOW of some period - for example, "within any 4 hour period", or "within any X consecutive timestamps"

there will always be a record by product_id every day, so closest product with the same id by timestamp for all other plans with a limit of say, 2 days? I know it's a complicated thing, if I could I'd redo this table, however there are millions of records already that I can't afford to lose

I was working on this a bit further. I don't think we're quite there, but thought that this example might at least help. Please take a look and then see if you can refine it further to do what you need:
// table
CREATE TABLE myPlans
(
  plan_id String,
  timestamp DateTime,
  client_id String,
  account_id UInt32,
  product_id UInt32,
  total UInt32
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
ORDER BY (plan_id,timestamp);

// query
SELECT
    plan_id,
    argMax(timestamp,max_sum_total) AS max_timestamp,
    argMax(client_id,max_sum_total) AS max_client_id,
    argMax(account_id,max_sum_total) AS max_account_id,
    argMax(product_id,max_sum_total) AS max_product_id,
    argMax(max_sum_total,max_sum_total) AS final_max_sum_total
FROM
(
    SELECT
       plan_id,
       timestamp,
       client_id,
       account_id,
       product_id,
       max(sum(total)) OVER myWindow AS max_sum_total
    FROM myPlans
    WHERE product_id = '8905'
    AND client_id = '7a954d98'
    GROUP BY plan_id, product_id, timestamp, client_id, account_id
    WINDOW myWindow AS
       (ORDER by timestamp
       RANGE BETWEEN 3600 PRECEDING AND 3600 FOLLOWING) // seconds
)
GROUP BY plan_id;

Query id: 0de8044b-938a-4c2e-b51c-09f5a9a0aea3

┌─plan_id─┬───────max_timestamp─┬─max_client_id─┬─max_account_id─┬─max_product_id─┬─final_max_sum_total─┐
│ 9d03    │ 2024-02-02 05:23:00 │ 7a954d98      │           4128 │           8905 │                 480 │
│ ff1d    │ 2024-02-02 16:38:00 │ 7a954d98      │           3127 │           8905 │                 800 │
└─────────┴─────────────────────┴───────────────┴────────────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────┘

2 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.006 sec.
